# How do I add a button in my Activity Maps?

Tags: java, android, xml, api, google-maps

I chose a Google Maps activity when I created the project, how do I add the button in the layout? 
Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm new in Android.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />
```

Layout:

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivityWifi"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
```

Comment: Try to wrap everything in a relative layout instead of a frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From StackOverFlow PT

```
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <fragment 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivityWifi"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[Como adicionar botão no Maps?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54439/como-adicionar-bot%C3%A3o-no-maps/54448#54448)

Answer (score 0):

[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.Use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) or a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Try this and change your button attribues as you desire

```
        <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<fragment 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="instead of match parent try to give a value so that it does not occupy the whole screen"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivityWifi"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
    android:layout_below="@id/map"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />
```

Comment: The FrameLayout was booting the map for the second time, edited the question